# How to automate the Java build process for IntelliJ IDEA 11 Projects?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, continuous-integration, build-automation

I am trying to set up a continuous integration system for a Java project I am working on. I plan to use Jenkins or some equivalent for the front end. The Java project is configured to use the IntelliJ IDEA IDE, version 11. The problem is there is no way to build IntelliJ IDEA 11 projects from a command line interface, which is required so it can interface with the CI front-end (Jenkins).

There are a couple of potential solutions I have looked into. They are as follows.

### Potential Solution # 1

Use the "Generate Ant Build" capability of IntelliJ IDEA. There are 2 problems with this solution:

1. It means I would have to either maintain the generated ant files as well as the IntelliJ idea configuration files, which I don't want to do, or I would have to programatically recreate the ant files periodically or on the fly, which is not feasible since there is no command line interface for this either.
2. It doesn't even work anyway. The project is fairly complex in that there are Java files that are configured to be excluded, and the generated ant files do not perform exclusion properly. Also, it looks like the dependencies are not even generated correctly. (Exhaustively) searching google tells me that this utility isn't even supported by IntelliJ, and it's use should be "avoided".

### Potential Solution # 2

Use a 3rd party application to dynamically generate ant build files, namely [ant-intellij-tasks](http://code.google.com/p/ant-intellij-tasks/). When I saw this project I was pretty excited, but unfortunately it looks like it hasn't been updated since 2009 and doesn't work with the new version of IntelliJ IDEA. I can't find any other libraries like this one that are up to date and working.

### Some Additional Notes

[This link](http://plugins.intellij.net/wishlist/item/?wid=20) suggests that others are having similar problems and want a command line interface (the link is a description of a plugin wanted for a contest - the source is IntelliJ IDEA themselves).

Has anyone else set up build automation using this tool set? How did you get it done? The answer I'm looking for ideally doesn't require management of additional configuration files and would allow me to type something on the command line and have the build happen.

Comment: Maybe try a Maven project? I find it much easier to manage a pom.xml than a complex ant build.

Comment: @MadcoreTom thanks for your reply. How would I use a Maven project in this case? The same problem exists: I have no way to export/convert my IntelliJ IDEA project to a Maven project.

Comment: Its a manual process which requires you to put all of the external dependencies and build tasks and such into the `pom.xml` file. You can then run maven from the commandline, and Jenkins integrates well with it too. You can build it from IntelliJ by adding a new Run configuration.
Perhaps someone else can elaborate on this process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting your project to fit with maven is easier to do than customizing Maven to work with your project structure.

Although you could do the latter, most of the time people don't design the way their project is laid out very cleanly at all, and after they adopt the maven layout, their project becomes much more manageable.

If you adapt the good patterns of a default maven project layout, IDEA will automatically read it and understand it completely - even sharing the same compiler output you use on the command line in the IDE. IDEA will use the pom.xml as its configuration file.

You can't do this with Ant, because it's a build process wrapper. Maven is not only a dependency management mechanism - it's an abstraction of a project, which an IDE can use to configure itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TeamCity to build your IntelliJ project. This works just fine, is automated, and there are many plugins that let you run command line tasks, ant tasks, etc.

This is one of the workflows I use regularly.

TeamCity functions as an Ivy repository. so you don't have to set up artifactory.

I do like maven though. It all really depends on what your needs are. Maven is great as long as you want do things the maven way - which is a pretty good workflow.

For the record few IDE's handle Maven projects well. IntelliJ does a decent job.

Answer (score 0):

using intelliJ, look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=870XIYMrlSo

automation (i.e. running jar file via terminal) requires adding maven-assembly-plugin to pom file

alternatively following works with terminal as of 2023-05-04

on macOS, open terminal

install maven using homebrew: brew install maven

check maven version just in case: mvn --version

navigate to the directory where maven will be installed and setup maven project (please adjust according to your project structure)

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.salman.app -DartifactId=myapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -Darchetypeversion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Navigate to folder with pom file

change pom xml (presented later)

run mvn package
navigate to directory where .jar is found
java -jar "name of jar file"

Suggestion for pom file (please update to adjust your project folder structure)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.salman.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>8</source>
          <target>8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.salman.app.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.salman.app.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```